# Dynamically create an object as needed without if checks

Tags: javascript, lodash

So I thought I was crazy, and I may be but this seems pretty simple.  Say I have this bit of code:

```
let a = {};
a.b.c.d.e.f.g = 'Something Awesome';
```

Now you can imagine the if-check nightmare that would have to take place to see if each level exists.  And even if I had a fancy looping way to do it, someone else has had to think this up.

I think CoffeeScript had something like this, but I can't seem to find anything on it.  I was also wondering if there was an ECMAScript6 or lodash way of doing the same type of thing?

Maybe something like:

```
set(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, 'Something Awesome');
```

And in that case even:

```
set(a, b, c, d, {e: {f: {g: 'Something Awesome'}}});
```

But the last option would wipe out anything that may exist in `e`, `f`, and `g`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are referring to lodash's [`_.set()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#set):

```js
const a = {};
_.set(a, 'b.c.d.e.f.g', 'Something Awesome');

console.log(a);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```